# Section+Subsection in the header AND chapter in the footer using book (memoir)

Tags: header-footer, lyx, memoir, chapters

I' writing my thesis in LyX with `book` (`memoir`) style.
I would like to personalize the headers and footers but I cannot use the `fancy` package since I'm in the `memoir` style.

So (being a novice in LaTeX) I tried to use pre-existing code that I modified to create a new page style.

The headers work fine; I got the section and the subsections respectively on the even and odd pages. I also got the page number on the footer on both pages but I cannot add the chapter number on the footer.

How could I proceed to get the footer with the current chapter number on each page in addition to the pre-existing page number?

```
  \nouppercaseheads

    \makepagestyle{mystyle}

    \makeheadrule {mystyle}{\textwidth}{\normalrulethickness} 

    \setlength{\headwidth}{\dimexpr\textwidth+\marginparsep+\marginparwidth\relax}


    %head
    \makeevenhead{mystyle}{\small\leftmark}{}{} 
    \makeoddhead{mystyle}{}{}{\small\rightmark}

    %foot
    \makeevenfoot {mystyle} {\small\thepage} {\small\leftmark} {}
    \makeoddfoot {mystyle} {} {\small\leftmark} {\small\thepage}

    \makeatletter

    \makepsmarks{mystyle}{%
      \createmark{section}{left}{shownumber}{}{\space}
      \createmark{subsection}{right}{shownumber}{}{\space}
      \createmark{chapter}{right}{shownumber}{\@chapapp\ }{\space }}

    \makeatother

    \pagestyle{mystyle}
```

Answer (score 1):

As `\chapter` starts a new page, there is not really a need to use a marks register. A conventional macro is sufficient. The following example uses `\mychapterfoot` that holds the string with the chapter/appendix title for the footer. Class `memoir` defines `\f@rhdr` that holds the header version of the chapter title. Hook points are

- `\memendofchapterhook` for `\chapter` without star.
- `\memchapstarinfo` for `\chapter*` with star before `\appendix`.
- `\memappchapstarinfo` for `\chapter` after `\appendix`.

Also the marks register for `\section` and `\subsection` titles should be cleared to prevent leaking those titles from the previous chapter. Since the first page of a chapter has usually a different page style and a `\subsection` title is not likely to be needed in the headers on that page, calling `\markboth{}{}` clears the marks register.

Example:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\mychapterfoot}{}
\g@addto@macro\memendofchapterhook{%
  \protected@xdef\mychapterfoot{%
    \@chapapp\ \thechapter\ \f@rhdr
  }%
  \markboth{}{}%
}
\let\org@memappchapstarinfo\memappchapstarinfo
\renewcommand{\memappchapstarinfo}[2]{%
  \org@memappchapstarinfo{#1}{#2}%
  \protected@xdef\mychapterfoot{\@chapapp\ \f@rhdr}%
  \markboth{}{}%
}
\let\org@memchapstarinfo\memchapstarinfo
\renewcommand*{\memchapstarinfo}[2]{%
  \org@memchapstarinfo{#1}{#2}%
  \protected@xdef\mychapterfoot{\@chapapp\ \f@rhdr}%
  \markboth{}{}%
}
\makeatother

\nouppercaseheads

\makepagestyle{mystyle}

\makeheadrule {mystyle}{\textwidth}{\normalrulethickness}

\setlength{\headwidth}{\dimexpr\textwidth+\marginparsep+\marginparwidth\relax}

%head
\makeevenhead{mystyle}{\small\leftmark}{}{}
\makeoddhead{mystyle}{}{}{\small\rightmark}

%foot
\makeevenfoot {mystyle} {\small\thepage} {\small\mychapterfoot} {}
\makeoddfoot {mystyle} {} {\small\mychapterfoot} {\small\thepage}

\makeatletter

\makepsmarks{mystyle}{%
  \createmark{section}{left}{shownumber}{}{\space}%
  \createmark{subsection}{right}{shownumber}{}{\space}%
  \renewcommand*{\chaptermark}[1]{}%
}

\makeatother

\pagestyle{mystyle}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Introduction}
\section{Section A}   
\subsection{Subsection B}
\newpage
\null   
\newpage
\null   
\chapter*{Nix}
\newpage
\null   
\end{document}
```